# Retrofit global error handle

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

Well, as we know, if the server's reponse is formatted like this:

```
{data: T,status: 200,error:""}
```

it's easy to have your base response like this:

```
public class HttpResult<T> {
    public int satus;
    public String error;
    public T data;
}
```

But what if the server return a JSON object when succeeding, and return another 
JSON object when failed, for example:

```
{
  "error": "Consumer key missing.",
  "status": 401
}
```

Now, how can I write a base class to encapsulate the response , for both succeed and error result?

Or should I let GSON parse different JSON objects in these two situations?

PS: I use GSON and retrofit + `rxjava` in this project...

Can anyone give me some advice?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In GSON library, you no need to handle it because if your parameter is missing it will automatically return null.

```
public class HttpResult<T> 
{
public int satus;
public String error;
public T data;
}
```

In above class you will get T as a null.

Answer (score 0):

When you use RxJava with Retrofit and define your request return type as `Observable<Result>` where `Result` is the object type you want to deserialize the response to, RxJava automatically emits only responses with HTTP status code between <200,300) which are considered as a success.. Every other response that gets back with a different status code is considered as a failure and will throw HttpException, thus you can do your error handling in onError callback as follows:

```
create(ApiService.class).someRequest()
    .subscribe((result) -> {
        // process your successful result
    }, (throwable) -> {
        if(throwable instanceof HttpException){
            switch (((HttpException) throwable).code()) {
                case 401: // handle this type of error
                default: // do whatever you want when you don't expect this type of error to happen
            }
        } else {
            // error returned is not related to a failed response 
            // and is probably a result of an exception along the 
            // way in the stream ( wrong (de)serialization, no network
            // connection or whatever you might mess up in the stream ) 
        }
    })
```

However, by the returned syntax you provided, I guess that your server ignores the HTTP standards and sends you the status code within the json body itself. And although this is not a good way to go and you might wanna discuss this with whoever is responsible for your backend, there is of course a way around. Retrofit itself cannot handle this without your help as it doesn't know which field corresponds to the status code. But you can modify the stream so that it behaves like you want. If you define the request with the returned HttpResult as you described, then you can do something like this:

```
create(ApiService.class).someRequest()
    .map((result) -> {
        if(result.status >= 200 && result.status < 300) return result.data;
           else throw new MyHttpException(result.error, result.status);
    })
    .subscribe((result) -> {
        // process your successful result
    }, (throwable) -> {
        if(throwable instanceof MyHttpException){
            switch (((MyHttpException) throwable).code) {
                case 401: // handle this type of error
                default: // do whatever you want when you don't expect this type of error to happen
            }
        } else {
            // error returned is not related to a failed response 
            // and is probably a result of an exception along the 
            // way in the stream ( wrong (de)serialization, no network
            // connection or whatever you might mess up in the stream ) 
        }
    })


public class MyHttpException extends RuntimeException {

    public String message; 

    public int code;

    public MyHttpException(String message, int code) {
        super(message);
        this.message = message;
        this.code = code;
    }
}
```

You can sugarcoat this a little bit by encapsulating the map operator into a `Transformer` so you can just apply it through `.compose()`. Unfortunately, there is no good way how to do this globally until the guys at Retrofit accept the pull request ( or implement it by their own ) for defining a global transformer for all requests.